# Hibernate versus Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

Just starting out with Java.  So having taken a Java Core class, given the choice between the two, which class should I take next -- Intro to Hibernate OR Grails for Java Web Apps?

Cheers!

Comment: Which do want to learn, how to do web apps in Groovy (using Spring and Hibernate under the covers), or Hibernate, an ORM?

Comment: I only have a choice between Hibernate or Grails. Those are the only 2 courses given that I can take this semester due to my work schedule.

Comment: I'm asking which you'd rather learn--there's no real answer to this question.

Comment: I want to learn both and will learn both.  But my schedule allows me only to take one of the two classes this semester.  So to re-phrase, which one should I take first?  (No toss up allowed, got to pick one over the other :-)

Answer (score 5):

IMO Grails is going to give you a much broader palette of tools to work with, as well as some exposure to Hibernate, so unless you are planning to work extensively with Hibernate, I would go with Grails.  Having said that, I would suggest learning the Spring framework before either.

Comment: You can get going in Grails fine without knowing Spring. To use it at medium-advanced level you'll need to know how Spring works but you can learn that as necessary as you go. In fact I would recommend this order (gets you moving faster).

Comment: I started out learning Grails without an in-depth appreciation of either Hibernate or Spring - this is fine and you'll make some progress with Grails, but you really do need some level of understanding of both Hibernate and Spring to really take advantage of the Grails framework. My next step would be to start to look at Grails, while taking a Core Spring course.

Comment: I only have a choice between Hibernate or Grails.  Those are the only 2 courses given that I can take this semester due to my work schedule.

Comment: I want to learn both and will learn both. But my schedule allows me only to take one of the two classes this semester. So to re-phrase, which one should I take first? (No toss up allowed, got to pick one over the other :-)

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I appreciate your feedback.  As an aside I 'totally disagree'  with the 'closed as not constructive' response from some others on this issue (?!?!?).  If I had not taken a Java Core class, for example, the answer would be simple -- take a Java Core class first.  How is this 'not constructive' to someone learning the art of Java?!?!  Ditto for 'opinions' (what, you only deal in 'facts'? Hardly). 'Extended discussion' (this is a forum where people 'discuss' things). ad nauseum.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest taking the course on Java EE 6. If you have only those two choices then Grails.

Comment: I only have a choice between Hibernate or Grails. Those are the only 2 courses given that I can take this semester due to my work schedule.

Comment: I only have a choice between Hibernate or Grails. Those are the only 2 courses given that I can take this semester due to my work schedule.

Comment: I want to learn both and will learn both. But my schedule allows me only to take one of the two classes this semester. So to re-phrase, which one should I take first? (No toss up allowed, got to pick one over the other :-)

Comment: Thanks Pangea. I appreciate your feedback. It answered my query -- a query that some others (except Nick) turned there nose up at.